# Enable compression for asp.net pagemethods

Tags: asp.net, performance, compression, pagemethods

Please how may we enable GZIP or DEFLATE for simple ASP.Net Page-Methods?

Looking at my test traffic in Fiddler shows 80%+ savings in download bytes when I apply compression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

The simple instructions here also work for ASP.NEt Page Methods

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx